# How do I install mapbox tilesets API on a mac that has Python 2.7 as default?

Tags: python, installation, mapbox

I have followed the instructions at https://github.com/mapbox/tilesets-cli/ but since the default Python version is 2.7 on a mac, Python3 is not used. How do I force this?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to shoehorn a tool built with Python 3 into Python 2, I would recommend using a tool like [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage multiple versions of Python on you device.

Especially given that Python 2.7 is not going to be maintained [past January 2020](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/#id2) and macOS is going to remove the Python 2.7 system dependency altogether in upcoming releases (see the "Scripting Language Runtimes > Deprecations" section of the [Catalina release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_catalina_10_15_beta_8_release_notes).)